# Why does Java compiler give "error: cannot find symbol" for LinkedList descendingIterator in the following code?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, linked-list, java-7

Why does this code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        List<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
        Iterator<Integer> i = l.descendingIterator();
    }
}
```

Generate this compiler error

```
./Playground/Playground.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Iterator<Integer> i = l.descendingIterator();
                               ^
  symbol:   method descendingIterator()
  location: variable l of type List<Integer>
1 error
```

- Here is the relevant [JavaDocs API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#method_summary)
- Running Java 7.. In case that is issue. Thought it had been around for donkeys years.
- [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-in-java/) is a canned example elsewhere.
- You could copy/paste code from here into this [website](https://code.sololearn.com/cVRUy2BwauK8#java) to see,

Comment: Try `LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();` Your type of `l` is a `List` and hence it doesn't have such a method on it.

Comment: @user7 If you've grown up using things like Spring - you learnt to always code to interfaces... So I stick by the accepted answer as the one I go with.

Comment: Coding to an interface is not specific to Spring. It is a natural thing to do.

Comment: If I am not mistaken main goal of programming-on-interface is to give us flexibility to change actual type of object handled by variable. If variable needs to be cast then that defeats the purpose of it because we no longer can use *any* subtype of interface but we are limiting acceptable objects to one type which was specified while casting.

Comment: If you want to code to an interface, you should use the `Deque` interface and not `List` here

Comment: Refusing to use the actual type for the variable because “always code to interfaces” and then perform a type cast to the actual type, is Cargo Cult programming. Well, @Pshemo already explained it, but it can’t be emphasized enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> List is an interface and LinkedList is an implementation of List

You have the option of explicit typecasting like the following

```
Iterator<Integer> i = ((LinkedList<Integer>)l).descendingIterator();
```

or change your code to be the following:

```
import java.util.*;
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
        Iterator<Integer> i = l.descendingIterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually prefer this. As it adheres to the Interface principle still

Comment: Sorry - re-edited again. You need to do a double cast. To get rid of compiler issues.

Comment: `( Iterator<Integer>)` is not needed. `descendingIterator()` called on `LinkedList<Integer>` will return `Iterator<Integer>` so that additional cast is irrelevant.

Comment: IT IS... To get rid of.. " Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error"

Comment: @JGFMK Where do you get that information? I don't see any warning when I use code like https://ideone.com/BOWb1Y.

Comment: @JGFMK I did, got only "No output.", no info about any error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bhxn.png

Answer (score 4):

Following the principal

> “Coding to interfaces, not implementation.”

I suggest to use the [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface that provides [descendingIterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#descendingIterator()) method

```
Deque<Integer> deque = new LinkedList<>();
Iterator<Integer> iterator = deque.descendingIterator();
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call `descendingIterator` on a `List` reference. The compiler doesn't know that the runtime type is a `LinkedList`, hence the compilation error.

If you want to access this method, you could define the reference as a `LinkedList`:

```java
LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: Ah right. I had it indoctrinated to always code Collections against interfaces. That rule of thumb is flawed. That would explain it. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, that would work, _if_ the method is defined as part of the interface contract.  Its not in this instance, as `LinkedList` implements additional methods outside of the `List` contract

Comment: You could code against the `Deque` interface, if you want to.