# Why is LinkedList descendingIterator not returning results in Sorted order?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I recently posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59591101/why-does-java-compiler-give-error-cannot-find-symbol-for-linkedlist-descendin) and I guess I am confused about LinkedList.
I thought the whole purpose was to be able to add information in randon order and to be able to pull it out in a sorted sequence.

So, if I had the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
        l.add(3);
        l.add(9);
        l.add(1);
        l.add(5);
        //Iterator<Integer> i = ( Iterator<Integer>)((LinkedList<Integer>)l).descendingIterator();
        //Iterator<Integer> i = l.descendingIterator();
        //while (i.hasNext()) {
        //    System.out.println(i.next());
        //}
        while (l.descendingIterator().hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(l.descendingIterator().next());

        }
    }
}
```

Or some version of this.. (as you can see I've tried a few... I would expect to see this as a result:

```
9
5
3
1
```

- What am I doing wrong?
- How should I fix the code?
- And is there a better solution?

---

### My agenda here is to maintain the sort as I add, akin to a b-tree.

This was the solution to my needs.

```
import java.util.*;
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        TreeSet<Integer> l = new TreeSet<>();
        l.add(3);
        l.add(9);
        l.add(1);
        l.add(5);
        //Iterator<Integer> i = ( Iterator<Integer>)((LinkedList<Integer>)l).descendingIterator();
        //Iterator<Integer> i = l.descendingIterator();
        //while (i.hasNext()) {
        //    System.out.println(i.next());
        //}

        System.out.println(l.pollLast());

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you sort the list?

Comment: You either sort the list, or use a sorted collection. The descending iterator only reverses the *sequential* order of the list, not a sorted order.

Comment: I thought the whole point was to maintain the sort for you as you go.. A bit like a b-tree.

Comment: No, not at all. Again, for a sorted collection, either sort it via collections sort, or use a sorted collection such as a Tree.

Comment: The API states what the iterator does pretty unambiguously. You may want to delete this question.

Comment: `while (l.descendingIterator().hasNext())` will loop forever, since you keep getting a *new* iterator and checking if it has a next, aka *first*, element.

Comment: Ah that explains that conundrum too. Cheers @Andreas This has been a useful post for me.  I was happy to comply with *HovercraftFullOfEels* suggestion. But SO won't let me delete question. (Reason:Others have invested time in answering).

Answer (score 0):

As per the API:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this deque in reverse sequential order

If you want the list sorted, you need to actually sort it via `Collections.sort(....)`, or use a sorted collection such as a Tree.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction with Tree. Updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

`descendingIterator` isn't the greatest name for a method. It iterates over the list in a reverse order (from the end to the beginning of the list).

If you want the values in an actual descending order, you'll need to sort the list first:

```java
Collections.sort(l);
```

Comment: Ah. You have hit the nail on the head as to the confusion on my part.

Comment: @Andreas got caught up in my train of thought, thanks for noticing - edited and fixed. My point still stands though - it's not a great name.